# Gradle: How to have a 'mock' buildType depend on a 'mock' buildType of another android library project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two gradle modules

- `:app` (android application)
- `:data` (android library)

`:app` depends on `:data`. I created an additional `buildType` for both modules called `mock`. When I build `:app` in the `mock` `buildType`, I want `:data` to be automatically built in the `mock` `buildType`. How can I achieve this?

I tried with something like the following in `:app`'s `build.gradle`:

```
mockCompile project(path: ':data', configuration: 'mock')
```

But this error is thrown:
`Error: Configuration with name 'mock' not found.`

`:data` has the following `buildTypes`:

```
android { 
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            shrinkResources true
        }
        mock {
            initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the line below to the build.gradle of you data module

`publishNonDefault true`

By default, android just publish the release build of your library, So the app module can not see the mock build of you data library.